# With RESTful API, how I don't make error in the client side if specific response json level is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

here is a simple response json:

```js
{
  "blog": {
    "title": "Blog"
    "paragraphs": [{
        "title": "paragraph1",
        "content": "content1"
      }, {
        "title": "paragraph2",
        "content": "content2"
      }, {
        "title": "paragraph3",
        "content": "content3"
      }

    ],
    "selectList": ["food", "play", "mood"]
  }
}
```

If something wrong with server, `paragraphs` property is `undefined`, how I avoid to make error in the client side? Even I still could get other datas successfully, like `blog.title`, `blog.selectList`...etc

if I don't want to use :

```js
if (response.blog && response.blog.paragraphs && response.blog.paragraphs....) {
  //do something
}
```

Because if there are many level in JSON object, it is not efficient way. Is anyone have smart and efficient way?

**UPDATE**

@MatthewHerbst said:just check the lowest property.

if I just check the lowest property(`response.blog.paragraphs`), that will make javascript error, crush my site. because the browser found `response.blog` is undefined. In the real case, if `response.blog` is `undefined`, I will get `response.error` property, then `if(response.blog.paragraphs)` will encounter error, because `response` object doesn't defined `blog` property in javascript. how I just check the lowest property?

Comment: you could return an http error if the server side processing failed or the content is not valid. then just check for the http error on the client side

Comment: Do you mean the objects in paragraph could be undefined too? if yes, then do you want to reject the particular object? or the entire paragraph array?

Comment: If the `paragraphs` is undefined, but I would like to get successful data like blog.title, blog.selectList..ect. In commonly, we used like if `(response.blog && response.blog.paragraphs....)`, if I use this way, it means response.blog.paragraphs not true (because `paragraphs` is undefined), then I will be return, and could not do next operation in `if`, any ideas?

Comment: sorry, please don't care `content`, I just want to know the better way to processing api response json data, because it isn't possible to check each property if it was defined in complex json format.

Comment: @SevenLee what others are saying is that at some point, the data is so bad that you just need to return a complete error.

Comment: And technically you could just do `if(response.blog.paragraphs)`. If anything is missing from the chain it will throw an error.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst if I don't want to use `if(response.blog.paragraphs)` to check property existed, how I continue the next operation, it will still use `blog.title`, `blog.selectList` to do other client side logic in the same request?

Comment: @SevenLee why do you need to check them all at once? Check them as you use them.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst the point is, if the json format has many level properties,  I need to check each level property until the property I need is defined. it is not efficient, thanks your responses :)

Comment: @SevenLee you don't. You can simply check for the lowest property you need. If anything in the middle is missing it will error out. And it's also extremely efficient: lookup time is constant and trivial.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst if I just check the lowest property, that will make javascript error, crush my site. because the browser found `response.blog` is not undefined, in the real case, if `response.blog` is undefined, I will get `response.error`, then `if(response.blog.paragraphs)` will be error, because response object doesn't defined `blog` property in javascript. how I just check the lowest property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [lodash](https://lodash.com) for this. E.g.

```
let paragraphs = _.get(response, 'blog.paragraphs', null);

if (!paragraphs) {
    // Couldn't get from response.
} else {
   // Do something with response.blog.paragraphs.
}
```

Comment: Aewsome! that is I need :)

Comment: if I need `blog.paragraphs.title.author.islike` property value, in this lodash way, if I need to check `blog.paragraphs`, `blog.paragraphs.title`, `blog.paragraph.title.authors` is defined?

Comment: Then you do `_.get(response, 'blog.paragraphs.title.authors', null)`. You get the value if there is such or `null`.

Comment: @SevenLee to be clear, this is no more efficient than what you originally have. It just hides what you have into a small little function. One could argue it's actually slower since it's an additional function call and you have to make your user download lodash just for a simple function call.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I don't think this is a matter of speed, but instead code readability and maintenance.

Comment: @nhaa123 I have nothing against your answer. But OPs comments above seem to desire "efficiency" which in my book means speed.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Fair enough.

Comment: it is better if there are speed and maintenance way, that is efficiency I think. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
var blogs = response.blogs;
if(blogs){
    //do something
    var paraData = blogs.paragraphs;
    if (paraData){
        // do some more fun
    }
}
```

**OR**

You can do something like this-

```
var arrKeys = Object.keys(blogs),
newBlogArr = [] // to get the filtered result;

(function(){
    for(i=0;i<arrKeys.length;i++){

    // to get the filtered defined objects only

        if(blogs[arrKeys[i]] !== null || blogs[arrKeys[i]] !== undefined){

            //Now simply push that array in newBlogArr;

            newBlogArr.push(blogs[arrKeys[i]]);
        }
    }
    return newBlogArr;
})();
```

Comment: The way won't resolve to get the certain property efficiently from complex levels JSON format, because you still go over each property, each level and check them is defined. If the property is deeply in nest hell, there will be many nest `if` hell.

Comment: @SevenLee it'll just do the first level check on objects, that whether that is defined or not, not gonna go into sub level objects!

Comment: I see...but it still need to check each level... we should try another way to get certain level property, I mean there are any algorithm or new mechanism support it?